# innodb_file_per_table setting on or off?

Tags: magento-enterprise, database

I've run into the bloated one innodb tablespace before and since then have opted for a file per table in innodb, innodb_file_per_table = 1. Because Magento has so many tables they say to only turn it on if you know what you are doing since there will be an fsync per table.

I'm at the point where I need to decide. Not like I can't reverse my decision but I'd like to get it right the first time. I know it will come down to our hardware, but my question to everyone is if anyone has this setting on and if so are you having any issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on Magento websites with a rather large catalog (1000000 products) and we have test both cases and one file per table is better for some reasons:

- The TRUNCATE TABLE operation is faster
- You can run OPTIMIZE TABLE to compact or recreate a tablespace

You can find more advantage and some potential disadvantages on MySQL website [Using Per-Table Tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

I hope this will help you to make a decision.

Comment: What concerns me is the open file handle and fsync per table. There will be a lot but we have pretty beefy, physical servers. Have you run into any issues in regards to these two factors?

Comment: On unix system you can find the maximum number of file descriptors for the whole system with this command `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. Magento have ~400 tables so it is not much compared to the number of available file descriptors. I never have any problem with this.

Comment: I second what @olcha says. The count of open file descriptors is much easier to change and tweak than the issue of _sane_ InnoDB architecture and maintenance.